# what is the correct way to get the origin header in a serverless deployed lambda fronted by api gateway?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am using the serverless framework to deploy a simple lambda (written in node/ express) behind api gateway...

In a `GET` I can see the `origin` header, but in a `POST` I cannot - it's not passed into my lambda function!

Anyone know why not and how to make it pass?

**Background:**

I did notice that in the `POST` the origin appears to be appended to the query string in the logs:

```
originalUrl: '/dev/endpoint?Origin=MY%20ORIGIN%20HERE',
```

So, I could extract the origin from the query string values, but I want to know if this is the correct way to do things on the serverless framework or should I be setting something to allow the API Gateway to send the origin through on a `POST` like it does on a `GET` ? Why are the 2 verbs behaving differently?

**My Code/ Config:**

the function definition in the serverless.yml looks like:

```
myGetFunction:
  handler: lambda/index.handler
  events:
    - http:
        path: /endpoint
        method: get
        cors: true
myPostFunction:
  handler: lambda/index.handler
  events:
    - http:
        path: /endpoint
        method: post
        cors: true
```

If I just put the following in my index.handler:

```
app.use((req, res) => {
  console.log('LOG REQUEST', req)
  res.send('interesting')
})
```

In my handler function, I only want to get the origin request header that was sent. In the `GET` it's easy: the cloudwatch logs show that it's available in the GET request in the headers object:

```
headers: 
  {
    accept: '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'cloudfront-forwarded-proto': 'https',
    'cloudfront-is-desktop-viewer': 'true',
    'cloudfront-is-mobile-viewer': 'false',
    'cloudfront-is-smarttv-viewer': 'false',
    'cloudfront-is-tablet-viewer': 'false',
    'cloudfront-viewer-country': 'GB',
    host: 'X.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    origin: 'MY ORIGIN HERE',
```

BUT: in the `POST` all the other headers are there, but `origin` is blank.

Comment: I can see the `origin` clearly in my headers in POST requests to my Lambda APIs.  Try moving that `console.log('LOG REQUEST')` outside of express and just inside your Lambda handler instead. Then, log your `event`.

Comment: good call thanks - will try and let you know

Comment: tried it and yeah it appears to be in the code itself, nothing to do with serverless/ api gateway / lambda proxy integration etc. - it could be express or serverless-http, but a grep in either codebase didn't show any obvious manipulation of origin shrug. thanks for your help.

Comment: If you could move away from `express` and `serverless-http`, much better. It will also make your Lambda more performant.

Comment: yeah agreed am doing just that - thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a bit of digging on this and ran into a couple realizations.

By default, it seems that no "origin" header passed in the API Gateway events. (I created a fresh serverless project, and just echoed back exactly what the API gateway event was.) So this is coming from some other source. I figured it may be a custom domain, and tested that. No dice.

My only other guess is that you have this behind some other layer (CloudFront?) that is forwarding these headers for you. If that ends up being the case, I would suggest you look and see if you can make it forward these headers for the `POST` request as it is for the `GET` request.

My only other final thought if none of the above is true is that there is some magic going on in some of the express middleware. I doubt this is the case.

For reference, this was my full `serverless.yml` and `handler.js` I tested with as well as a full unaltered event object I got in the endpoint.

```
service: so-test

provider:
name: aws
runtime: nodejs8.10

functions:
myGetFunction:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
    - http:
        path: /endpoint
        method: get
        cors: true
myPostFunction:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
    - http:
        path: /endpoint
        method: post
        cors: true
```

And the nodejs code:

```
'use strict';

module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {
return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
    message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
    input: event,
    }),
};
};
```

Finally the response object

```
{
    "message": "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!",
    "input": {
        "resource": "/endpoint",
        "path": "/test/endpoint",
        "httpMethod": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
            "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
            "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
            "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
            "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
            "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "US",
            "Host": "so-test.serverless-examples.com",
            "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36",
            "Via": "2.0 f92491812e422470607f365e923929b5.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
            "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "6AwZPV3uCYxseJIAmsGzhApzRostCiLXwwM3XsbSJP4K8hQx11MSgw==",
            "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5c086dd9-bce03ab0c216116fa6de9786",
            "X-Forwarded-For": "55.55.55.555, 70.132.32.155",
            "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
            "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
        },
        "multiValueHeaders": {
            "Accept": [
                "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
            ],
            "Accept-Encoding": [
                "gzip, deflate, br"
            ],
            "Accept-Language": [
                "en-US,en;q=0.9"
            ],
            "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": [
                "https"
            ],
            "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": [
                "true"
            ],
            "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": [
                "false"
            ],
            "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": [
                "false"
            ],
            "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": [
                "false"
            ],
            "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": [
                "US"
            ],
            "Host": [
                "so-test.serverless-examples.com"
            ],
            "upgrade-insecure-requests": [
                "1"
            ],
            "User-Agent": [
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"
            ],
            "Via": [
                "2.0 f92491812e422470607f365e923929b5.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"
            ],
            "X-Amz-Cf-Id": [
                "6AwZPV3uCYxseJIAmsGzhApzRostCiLXwwM3XsbSJP4K8hQx11MSgw=="
            ],
            "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": [
                "Root=1-5c086dd9-bce03ab0c216116fa6de9786"
            ],
            "X-Forwarded-For": [
                "55.55.55.555, 70.132.32.155"
            ],
            "X-Forwarded-Port": [
                "443"
            ],
            "X-Forwarded-Proto": [
                "https"
            ]
        },
        "queryStringParameters": null,
        "multiValueQueryStringParameters": null,
        "pathParameters": null,
        "stageVariables": null,
        "requestContext": {
            "resourceId": "mftg6x",
            "resourcePath": "/endpoint",
            "httpMethod": "GET",
            "extendedRequestId": "RdYZ7HaxoAMFQYQ=",
            "requestTime": "06/Dec/2018:00:31:21 +0000",
            "path": "/test/endpoint",
            "accountId": "800708648372",
            "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
            "stage": "dev",
            "domainPrefix": "so-test",
            "requestTimeEpoch": 1544056281163,
            "requestId": "410632a3-f8ee-11e8-a7e2-7d886f93a0e4",
            "identity": {
                "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
                "accountId": null,
                "cognitoIdentityId": null,
                "caller": null,
                "sourceIp": "55.55.55.555",
                "accessKey": null,
                "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
                "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
                "userArn": null,
                "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36",
                "user": null
            },
            "domainName": "so-test.serverless-examples.com",
            "apiId": "txctij0cnp"
        },
        "body": null,
        "isBase64Encoded": false
    }
}
```

Comment: that is fascinating thanks - I hadn't put CF or anything in front yet - i agree it's possible but unlikely express - I am going to try my repro pulling express out first and then pulling more and more bits out until I can see what's doing it. i will let you know!

Comment: i just tried keeping my infrastructure the same and wrote the same handler code as you (no expressjs etc.)

> By default, it seems that no "origin" header passed in the API Gateway events.

I got an origin header passed through - one isn't created - you need to set it in postman in your request yourself (emulating the browser behaviour.) sorry I didn't clarify this in my statement.

Comment: You have answered my question though - if I don't use express and serverless-http and just use plain node code in my handler like you did then for both the GET and the POST i see the origin header. So it's definitely nothing to do with serverless or api gateway. Thanks loads for your help!